# Spring boot multiple contexts - one for public error

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I have this requirement, where "com.my.application/" should show customized 404 error page while "com.my.application/data" should work properly.

Following context-path is configured in application.properties

server.context-path=/data

What are my options? How can I keep context-path "/" and "/data" both alive?

Comment: its all about mappings declared by you in controllers.

Comment: Can you please tell more detail. Request mapping will be based on context-path. So if I have @RequestMapping("/"), in controller, it will correspond to url: "com.my.application/data".

Comment: I guess what I want is something like static welcome-content outside context-path.