# CAS 5.3.1 and random 404

Tags: cas

We are randomly redirected to domain by CAS and end up in 404 response. We thought to create static 404 error page. But problem is CAS has embedded tomcat which is responsive to domain.com/cas context-path. And we want error page on domain.com/.

How can I achieve that?

Related post I created: [Spring boot multiple contexts - one for public error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55247140/spring-boot-multiple-contexts-one-for-public-error?noredirect=1#comment97227495_55247140)

Answer (score 0):

> But problem is CAS has embedded tomcat which is responsive to domain.com/cas context-path. And we want error page on domain.com/.

Spring Boot applications that use an embedded tomcat container only respond to requests mapped to the context-path, which in your case is /cas. There is no such thing as "/" or ROOT when dealing with an embedded container.

So you'll need to either use an external tomcat instance, or change your context-path to "/".